# NFT's may be a new money laundering horizon

Tags: cryptocurrency, non-fungible-tokens

I made some experiments with the creation of NFTs on various platform like open sea and mintable.
No one reacted on the NFTs  and it's not strange because they clearly suck!

But i saw some ridiculous NFTs  sold for millions of dollars. After that in my mind come one this thought, can people use the web 3.0 in order to launder money?

Basically you make an NFT and sell it for millions and the someone else or you from an  account buy this NFT and after that declare the profit.

Comment: Yes, they can do it like that.

Comment: "Web 3.0" is a marketing term with no defined meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> can people use the web 3.0 in order to launder money?

Web 3.0 is not well defined.  It is undoubted that people can use cryptographic tokens, both fungible and non-fungible, to turn the profits of crime into spendable fiat currency.  If you define web 3.0 as using cryptocurrency on the web then yes.  For examples you could look at [Web3 is going just great](https://web3isgoinggreat.com/).